# PHP object array

Tags: javascript, php

I am wondering if there is any PHP array that is capable of storing a data structure similar to the below javascript variable 'item'

```
var item = {id: 10, weight: "100g", qty: 1};
basketArray.push(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$basketArray = array();

$basketArray['id'] = 10;
$basketArray['weight'] = '100g';
$basketArray['qty'] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal array:

```
<?php
    $array = [
       "foo" => "bar",
       "bar" => "foo",
    ];
?>
```

push elements to array:

```
<?php 
    array_push($array, "barFoo", "fooBar");
?>
```